# Using lapply to perform multiple operations on many elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, element, lapply

I currently have a list of 150 elements that each contain 5 columns and varying length from 200-1000 rows a piece. I want to perform a split inside each element of my list on the data frame. I essentially want to make a new list of the same length but with very different data frames inside the list. I know what I want to do on each element but cannot seem to find the correct method to implement this over the entire list. An example list is below:

```
>ex

$`66th & Center`

    Bike CheckoutKioskName ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time    UserRole
24583  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:08:58 2013-02-28 15:09:08 Maintenance
24584  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:30 2013-02-28 15:09:54 Maintenance
24585  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:51 2013-02-28 15:10:11 Maintenance
24586  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:09 2013-02-28 15:10:25 Maintenance
24587  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:24 2013-02-28 15:10:47 Maintenance
24588  191     66th & Center   66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:49 2013-02-28 15:11:16 Maintenance

$`67th & Frances`
      Bike CheckoutKioskName ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time    UserRole
24598  173    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-02-28 16:39:27 2013-02-28 16:39:27 Maintenance
24599  230    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-02-28 16:39:43 2013-02-28 16:39:43 Maintenance
24600  279    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-02-28 16:40:22 2013-02-28 16:40:22  Subscriber
24616  102    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-03-09 13:38:20 2013-03-09 18:41:42  Subscriber
24617   59    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-03-09 13:39:09 2013-03-09 18:41:41  Subscriber
24619  279    67th & Frances  67th & Frances 2013-03-12 15:03:56 2013-03-12 15:04:53      Member

$`67th & Pine`
      Bike CheckoutKioskName ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time    UserRole
24601  258       67th & Pine     67th & Pine 2013-02-28 16:57:08 2013-02-28 21:40:22 Maintenance
24602  258       67th & Pine  Aksarben Drive 2013-03-01 15:34:21 2013-03-01 20:36:37 Maintenance
24603  261       67th & Pine  Aksarben Drive 2013-03-01 15:34:25 2013-03-01 20:36:50 Maintenance
24622  279    67th & Frances     67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:23:16 2013-03-12 17:27:03  Subscriber
24623   59    67th & Frances     67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:23:29 2013-03-12 18:53:52      Member
24624  116    Aksarben Drive     67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:38:05 2013-03-12 18:51:46      Member
```

An example of what I want to do is below. I have just taken one element from the list to do my initial testing on:

```
tes <- ex$`66th & Center`

c.tes <- tes[tes$CheckoutKioskName == '66th & Center',c('CheckoutKioskName','Checkout_date_time')]
c.tes$event <- rep(-1,length(c.tes))
names(c.tes) <- c('Station','Time','Event')
r.tes <- tes[tes$ReturnKioskName == '66th & Center', c('ReturnKioskName','Return_date_time')]
r.tes$event <- rep(1,length(r.tes))
names(r.tes) <- c('Station','Time','Event')
c.r.tes <- rbind(c.tes,r.tes)
c.r.tes <- c.r.tes[with(c.r.tes,order(Time)),]
c.r.tes$Tlapsed <- c(NA,c.r.tes[2:nrow(c.r.tes),c('Time')] - c.r.tes[-nrow(c.r.tes),c('Time')])
```

Which returns:

```
c.r.tes
         Station                Time Event Tlapsed
24583  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:08:58    -1      NA
245831 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:08     1      10
24584  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:30    -1      22
24585  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:51    -1      21
245841 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:09:54     1       3
24586  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:09    -1      15
245851 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:11     1       2
24587  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:24    -1      13
245861 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:25     1       1
245871 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:47     1      22
24588  66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:10:49    -1       2
245881 66th & Center 2013-02-28 15:11:16     1      27
```

I want to do this exact same process but for every element of the list. I would like my final output to be something like `ex.events` which would contain 150 elements all of which would have a data.frame in the same format as my `tes` example.

I have attempted to do this myself using `lapply` which I believe to be the most efficient way, but I cannot seem to get the errors to stop coming. Here is the syntax I have tried:

```
setNames(lapply(us, function(e){
c.e <- ex$e[ex$e$CheckoutKioskName == e ,c('CheckoutKioskName','Checkout_date_time')]
c.e$event <- rep(-1,length(c.e))
names(c.e) <- c('Station','Time','Event')
r.e <- ex$e[ex$e$ReturnKioskName == e , c('ReturnKioskName','Return_date_time')]
r.e$event <- rep(1,length(r.e))
names(r.e) <- c('Station','Time','Event')
c.r.e <- rbind(c.e,r.e)
c.r.e <- c.r.e[with(c.r.e,order(Time)),]
c.r.e$Tlapsed <- c(NA,c.r.e[2:nrow(c.r.e),c('Time')] - c.r.e[-nrow(c.r.e),c('Time')])
}),us)
```

I again just want the end result to be the same length of a list I started with but with each element having the code done on it.

I have really been struggling with this so I appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the necessary data to make this into a **reproducible** example, per the R tag description and MCVE requirement. Here's the R tag description: *R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, and graphics. **Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. Use `dput()` for data** and specify all non-base packages with library calls. For statistical questions please use http://stats.stackexchange.com.*

Comment: Can you show the error and also a small reproducible example as the other commenter said.

Comment: I am getting an error in the `names()` line of: 

Error in names(c) <- c("Station", "Time", "Event") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: I am sorry about not posting the data. I have edited my original post. I believe I have the changes you have asked for.

Comment: Your error can occur if `c.e <- ex$e[...` or `r.e<-ex$e[...` returns `NULL`. So check that.

Comment: That is what is happening, but I am not sure why it is returning `NULL`

Comment: Why has to do with what `us` is over which `lapply` is applying. What is that? Also, put the output of `str(ex)` in your question.

Comment: That is the names of the elements in the list. I thought I could just do `lapply(fz, function(e) { c.e <- e[e$CheckoutKioskName ....so on and so on})` but when I tried that I was getting an unambiguous error.


The output of `ex` is there along with the `tes` output.

Comment: Try `ex[[e]]` instead of `ex$e` in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer because a full answer will require a `dput` of your input data and description of what `us` is. However, it should give you some hints at your problem. Let's assume that your data is:

```
ex <- list(`66th & Center`=data.frame(CheckoutKioskName=c(1,2), ReturnKioskName=c(3,4)), `67th & Frances`=data.frame(CheckoutKioskName=c(5,6), ReturnKioskName=c(7,8)))
```

and `us` is (Note that no back-quotes are used):

```
us <- c("66th & Center","67th & Frances")
```

Then,

```
lapply(us, function(e) print(ex$e$CheckoutKioskName))
##NULL
##NULL
##[[1]]
##NULL
##
##[[2]]
##NULL
```

results in `NULL`s. However:

```
lapply(us, function(e) print(ex[[e]]$CheckoutKioskName))
##[1] 1 2
##[1] 5 6
##[[1]]
##[1] 1 2
##
##[[2]]
##[1] 5 6
```

gives us what we want.

Comment: When I try using ex[[e]] instead of ex$e I am thrown a different error which is ` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "event", value = c(-1, -1)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1777 ` I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I feel like my logic is fine as I work through line by line. I have tried `lapply(ex, function(e){ 
                                      c <- e[e$CheckoutKioskName == e, ` and so on. I but when I do that I am getting an error of  `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: @Brett: that **may** be because `rep(-1,length(c.e))` should be instead `rep(-1,nrow(c.e))`. I emphasize the **may** because without a MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example), we can only guess at what all your issues are. The details matter.

Comment: @Brett: You should also run your original `tes` script with `67th & Pine` as that is a richer test case.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! All I had to do was that little fix along with the `ex[[e]]` instead of `ex$e`. I did have to add a `print(c.r.e)` at the end of the `lapply` function, but I did end up solving my problem.

Comment: @Brett: I'm glad to help, but next time please remember to provide that MCVE. People like akrun and Hack-R are very experienced and can solve your problem much more quickly, but they have to review all the questions that come in and do not have the time to reverse engineer everyone's issues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `seq_along()` in `lapply()` function since you need to extract names of individual elements:

```
dfList <- lapply(seq_along(ex), function(i){ 
     # TEMP VARS
     item <- names(ex)[[i]]
     tempdf <- ex[[i]]  

     # CHECKOUT SUBSET
     c.e <- tempdf[tempdf$CheckoutKioskName == item, 
                   c('CheckoutKioskName','Checkout_date_time')] 
     c.e$event <- rep(-1, nrow(c.e))                           # OR c.e$event <- -1
     names(c.e) <- c('Station','Time','Event') 

     # RETURN SUBSET
     r.e <- tempdf[tempdf$ReturnKioskName == item, 
                   c('ReturnKioskName','Return_date_time')] 
     r.e$event <- rep(1, nrow(r.e))                            # OR r.e$event <- 1
     names(r.e) <- c('Station','Time','Event') 

     # COMBINED 
     df <- rbind(c.e, r.e) 
     df <- df[with(df,order(Time)),] 
     df$Tlapsed <- c(NA,df[2:nrow(df),c('Time')] - df[-nrow(df),c('Time')])
     return(df)    
})

dfList <- setNames(dfList, us)
```